# Problema url GET laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Actualmente estoy trabajando roles, y pues hasta el momento todo ha ido funcionando bien, hasta que note algo en uno de los modulos, el problema es el siguiente, tengo dos usuarios de rol, el admin puede consultar todos los usuarios de todos los referidos, mientras el usuario referido solo puede consultar solo sus propios usuarios, y esta bien funciona, el problema es la url.

```html
http://statisticrol.test/panel/selector?_token=wlk3QhMgeki2d96OlzYRZQ42L7VCOY2kMdAS5OQ8&tipo=3
```

si decido cambiar el numero 3 por el 5 estaria viendo los usuarios de otro referido, quizas esto les ha pasado a muchos, y es obvio que es un problema de privacidad y seguridad con lo que pretendo, acaso alguna manera de ocultar o encryptar una ruta get? o que debo hacer en estos casos?

Esta es mi vista

```html
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')

  <section class="content">
  <!-- <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"> -->
<table style="width:98%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" border="1">
<tr><td>  
  @if(Session::has('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{Session::get('success')}}
      </div>
      @endif

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Usuarios votantes</h3><br>
        
            <table style="width:100%;" border="0" >
   <tr><td style="width:50%;" border="0">           


   <form action="{{route('usuario.fecha')}}" method="get" >
      <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
        <tr><td style="width:100%;" border="0">  
   
                       <label for="from">Desde</label>
                       <input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Año-Mes-Dia">
                       <label for="to" >Hasta</label>
                       <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Año-Mes-Dia">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>               
            </td></tr>
            </table> 
      </form></td>
  
   
   <td style="width:25%;" border="0">  

   <form action="{{route('usuario.selector')}}" method="get" style="width:50%;" border="1" >
   
   <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
   <tr><td style="width:100%;" border="0">  
   
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                       <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class=" form-control"  value="{{ old('tipo') }}"  required style="width:150px">
                        @foreach($usuariosOpciones as $user_id => $usuario_ad)
                          <option value="{{ $user_id }}">{{ $usuario_ad }}</option>
                       @endforeach
                   </select>         
              </td>
       
        <td style="width:50%;" border="1">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>               
     </td></tr>
            </table> 
             </form></td>
    
    
  
    
   <td style="width:25%;">  
      <form action="{{route('usuario.cedula')}}" method="get">

   <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
   <tr><td style="width:50%;" border="0">  
   
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="number" name="cc" id="cc" min="1111111" max="9999999999" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{ old('cedula') }}" placeholder="cedula"  style="width:100%;"></td>
     
 <td style="width:50%;" border="1"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>               
         </td></tr>
            </table> 
    </form>
    
   </td></tr>
            </table>
   
   <br>
        
          <div class="table-container">
            <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped table-bordered">
             <thead>
               <th>Usuario_ad</th>
               <th>Nombre</th>
               <th>Apellido</th>
               <th>Cedula</th>
               <th>Telefonos</th>
               <th>Direccion</th>
               <th>barrio</th>
               <th>Lugar_v</th>
               <th>Mesa_v</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Ciudad</th>
               <th>Editar</th>
               <th>Eliminar</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
              @if($usuarios->count()) 
              @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)  
              <tr>
                <td>{{$usuario->usuario_ad}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->apellido}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->cedula}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->telefonos}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->direccion}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->barrio}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->lugar_votacion}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->mesa_votacion}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$usuario->ciudad}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{action('UsuarioController@edit', $usuario->id)}}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                <td>
                  <form action="{{action('UsuarioController@destroy', $usuario->id)}}" method="post">
                   {{csrf_field()}}
                   <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                   </form>
                </td>
               </tr>
               @endforeach 
               @else
               <tr>
                <td colspan="8">No hay registro !!</td>
              </tr>
              @endif
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </td></tr>
            </table> 
       <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
      {{ $usuarios->links() }}
    </div>
  </div> 

</section>
 
@endsection
@section('scripts')

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({});
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script> 
@endsection
```

la seccion en cuestion es la que tiene la ruta usuario.selector, y este mi metodo.

```html
 /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
           $registrado = \Auth::user()->tipos_usuarios_id;
           $filtro = \Auth::user()->name;
 
        if($registrado == 1)

          {

            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
            $user=user::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
            $conteo=User::count();
            return view('usuario.ecuenta')->with(["user" => $user, "conteo" => $conteo]);

          }

         if($registrado == 2)

          {

           $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['referido']);
           $user=user::where("name", $filtro)->paginate(1);
           $conteo=User::where("name", $filtro)->count();
           return view('usuario.ecuenta')->with(["user" => $user, "conteo" => $conteo]);
       
          }

    }
```

Comment: creo que la solucion estaria en los middlewares en las rutas, ya que si Hasheas las rutas de todas formas aun seran vulnerables.

Comment: Y como puedo usar un mildware en mi caso especifico?

Comment: Revisa Policies de Laravel, eso te ayudará: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

Answer (score 0):

si lo que deseas es que no se muestre la ruta usa `redirect`

```html
if($registrado == 2)

          {

           $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['referido']);
           $user=user::where("name", $filtro)->paginate(1);
           $conteo=User::where("name", $filtro)->count();
           return redirect('usuario.ecuenta')->with(["user" => $user, "conteo" => $conteo]);
       
          }
```